# how to change the angular tab using button in content?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

This is component.html part. How can I change to next tab from button of tab1 to tab2 and tab2 to tab 3 and so on?

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 
        <button (click)=?>next</button>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2
        <button (click)=?>previous</button>
        <button (click)=?>next</button>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3
        <button (click)=?>previous</button>
        <button (click)=?>submit</button>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: in content of mat-tab i want to make button which will help me switching to next tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider following the `tab-panel` html structure.

```
<mat-tab-group #allTabs>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">
    <p>Tab 1 Content</p>
    <button mat-raised-button tabindex="-1" type="button" 
     color="warn" (click)='moveToSelectedTab("Tab 2")'>Move to Tab 2</button>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 2">
    <p>Tab 2 Content</p>
    <button mat-raised-button tabindex="-1" type="button" 
    color="warn" (click)='moveToSelectedTab("Tab 1")'>Move to Tab 1</button>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

You can find all the tabs in the component, and look for the tab **`label`** you want to move, 
after that call the click method on that.

```
moveToSelectedTab(tabName: string) {
  for (let i =0; i< document.querySelectorAll('.mat-tab-label-content').length; i++) {
  if ((<HTMLElement>document.querySelectorAll('.mat-tab-label-content')[i]).innerText == tabName) 
     {
        (<HTMLElement>document.querySelectorAll('.mat-tab-label')[i]).click();
     }
   }
}
```

**[Demo showing Tab Switching from Button present in content of different tab](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-tabs-click-from-inside-other-tab-redirect?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **selectedIndex** attribute of the **MatTabGroup** component.

HTML:

```
<mat-tab-group #tabgroup>
  
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 
    <button (click)="changeIndex(tabgroup,1)">next</button>
  </mat-tab>
  
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2
    <button (click)="changeIndex(tabgroup,0)">previous</button>
    <button (click)="changeIndex(tabgroup,2)">next</button>
  </mat-tab>
  
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3
    <button (click)="changeIndex(tabgroup,1)">previous</button>
    <button (click)="submit()">submit</button>
  </mat-tab> 
  
</mat-tab-group>
```

TS:

```
changeIndex(tabgroup: MatTabGroup, number: number){
  tabgroup.selectedIndex = number;
}
  
submit(){ //Code for submitting}
```